# Jenkins pipeline convert all parameters to lowercase

Tags: groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can I convert all the parameters in a Jenkins pipeline to lowercase. Similar to trim, is there an attribute that one could add as part of the parameter declaration,

For trim, I have something like below,

```
parameters {
   string defaultValue: '', description: 'Some dummy parameter', name: 'someparameter', trim: true
}
```

In my pipeline job, I have more than 10 string parameters and would like to convert them all to lowercase

Comment: you can call toLowerCase() on them when you use them

Comment: I'm passing the parameters to shell in a stage like below, per your comment can i do like  stage("test") { step {  script { sh ''' someparameter=${someparameter}.toLowerCase() ''' } } }

Answer (score 13):

Here's one approach:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string ( name: 'testName', description: 'name of the test to run')
    }
    stages {
        stage('only') {
            environment {
                TEST_NAME=params.testName.toLowerCase()
            }
            steps {
                echo "the name of the test to run is: ${params.testName}"
                sh 'echo "In Lower Case the test name is: ${TEST_NAME}"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I do have more than 10 string parameters and also i'm using env vars for few other stuffs, I think it will not be a good idea to set parameters as env vars. Will it be possible to refer params.testName.toLoweCase() inside the shell?

Answer (score 8):

```
sh """ ${the_parameter.toLowerCase()} """
```

1. Need to use double quote so you have a GString
2. Put the `toLowerCase()` function call inside the brace for shell to refer back to groovy

Comment: what happens if I just use single quotes ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually one can just do

```
VAR = "${VAR.toLowerCase()}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to use this for my use case. It will not convert but it will prevent passing wrong value.

```
validatingString(name: "MYVAR",
                 defaultValue: "",
                 regex: /^[a-z0-9]+$/,
                 failedValidationMessage: "",
                 description: "")
```