# How to fix --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase in a Jenkins delcarative pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

In our Jenkinsfile, we're trying to tag the docker images with the branch name like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          def app = docker.build("my_private_server/myapp/myapp-${env.BRANCH_NAME}:${env.BUILD_ID}")
          withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'my-credentials', url: 'https://my_private_server.example.com') {
            app.push()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We use JIRA, so our branches are named like this `PROJ-2454-implement-login-box`

Which results in this:

```
+ docker build -t my_private_server.example.com/myapp/myapp-PROJ-2454-implement-login-box:17 .
invalid argument "my_private_server.example.com/myapp/myapp-PROJ-2454-implement-login-box:17" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Meaning, that we can't have `PROJ` in the branch name, which isn't going to work because this is our process.  So we need to make it lowercase somehow.  How do we make the string lowercase?

Comment: In general, the Jenkins pipeline is using Groovy syntax. So, related posts about manipulating strings in Groovy should also work for your case, like this with `toLowerCase`: [Jenkins pipeline convert all parameters to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819405/jenkins-pipeline-convert-all-parameters-to-lowercase)

Comment: That post solved it. Thanks